# Why doesn't the jlabel array show in the panel?

Tags: java

`star` is my `char[]`:

```
Label[] labels = new JLabel[20];
for (int k = 0; k < star.length; k++) {
  labels[k] = new JLabel("x");
  xPanel.add(labels[k]);
}
```

Comment: This is for a hangman program

Comment: Cn you share ["Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: It's hard to comment based on this limited code you've posted. Are you sure that xPanel is added to your JFrame somewhere?

Comment: Why you iterate over `star` ?

Comment: `Label[] labels = new JLabel[20];` JLabel isn't a subclass Label, so this won't work. Should this be `JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[20];` ?

Comment: Yes the xPanel is added to frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        final JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[20]; // replaced Label with JLabel
        for (int k = 0; k < labels.length; k++) { // replaces star with labels
            labels[k] = new JLabel("x");
            frame.add(labels[k]);
        }
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

and the result (after frame resizing is):

[image: frame screenshot]

Comment: String[] wordsIncluded = {"apple", "hello", "ferrari"};
        Random random = new Random();
        String word = wordsIncluded[random.nextInt(wordsIncluded.length)];
        char[] star = word.toCharArray(); 
         JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[20]; 
        for (int k = 0; k < star.length; k++) { 
            labels[k] = new JLabel("x");
            xPanel.add(labels[k]);
        }

Comment: Did you try it? If I add the part creating star array it still work. Please edit your question and add relevant details...

Answer (score 0):

```
panel.updateUI();
```

You must use this method to update the jlabel array